# Why Does Nothing Appear When Using Time.Sleep and print({text}, end="")?

Tags: python

I have been able to narrow down the problem to it not working when two conditions are true. When you are running it through the commend prompt, which I'll need for getch in the future, and when changing the end= from \n to anything else for print, this is needed because I don't want a newline character at the end of each char...

Here is what I mean:

```
import time

for eachchar in 'time time time time time':
    time.sleep(.1)
    print(eachchar, end="")
input()
```

This will not work, however, getting rid the end="" part will make it function, of course with the undesirable newline character appearing after each bit of text...

Weirdly, works perfectly when run from the shell. It's only when the specific condition of running it through the cmd prompt AND using the end= to change it to anything other than the default \n character... Any workarounds?

Comment: this works for me.  it prints "time time time time time".  What is the difference between running from the shell and cmd prompt?

Comment: flush it manually in each loop iteration (`sys.stdout.flush()` after importing `sys`).

Comment: pax, thank you so much, worked like a charm!